# Linked Date Pickers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using the linked date time picker given at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

My problem is with picking up the date and time for an intra day event.

For example in the first text area select this date and time :02/26/2015 8:48 AM
Now attempt to select this date and time in the second text area:02/26/2015 9:20 AM which does not happen.

The problem can be simulated on the above link.

Comment: I can select both dates (in the linked sample) on latest Chrome and FF.

Comment: Your right.  It's seems to be a bug.  You can get the second date and time if you select the next day (27th), adjust clock time forward past 8:48 am, and then move the day back again to the 26th.  The problem is caused by the time in the second picker defaulting to a time earlier than the first.

Comment: You can take this up with the developer.  There is already a bug report about this issue here https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/825

Comment: Thanks,will do that.